# Laravel 8: how to send email with attachment using markdown

Tags: laravel

I would like to know how to include an attachment when sending an email using laravel and markdown.
This is the class **InvoiceEmail extends Mailable**

```
  protected $data;
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from('tes@test.com')->subject('Order')->markdown('emails.invoiceEmail')->with('data',$this->data);
    }
```

In the controller called OrderController I send the email:

```
   $customerPDF = 'file.pdf';

   $data = array(
        'name' => $request->vendor_name,
        'company' => $request->company,
        'vat'=> $request->vat,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'url' => Route('vendor.reg.enable.account',$enableCode)
    );


    Mail::to($request->email)->send(new InvoiceEmail($data));
```

My question is: how can I attach the customerPDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add attach method call to InvoiceEmail@build

```php
 public function build()
{
    return $this->from('tes@test.com')
                ->subject('Order')
                ->markdown('emails.invoiceEmail')
                ->with('data',$this->data)
                ->attach(asset($this->data->pdf_file), ['mime' => 'application/pdf']);
}
```